# How can I determine if a server needs to restart after IIS changes?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I am attempting to add some basic features to IIS 7 under Windows Server 2008, such as Logging. I am doing this by adding a new Role Service like "HTTP Logging". Or installing "Common HTTP Features".

But when I try to do so, I am given a warning:

> This server might need to be restarted after the installation completes.

How can I determine for sure if the server will require a reboot?

Comment: How are you making these changes? Via `dism`?

Comment: @jscott Server Manager UI -> Web Server (IIS) -> Role Services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wizard will prompt you after the installation is completed to reboot if it's required. Most roles/features doesn't require it, so you should trust it. The warning you see is just a warning - that you MIGHT have to reboot.

Comment: How can I determine before the installation though? This is a live server and I'd like to only install Role Services that doesn't require a reboot.

Comment: @JBurace No idea at all. You can install the feature, and then just do the reboot when you have the window..

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite for sure, but you can use the -whatif switch with powershell's uninstall-windowsfeature:

uninstall-windowsfeature -name rolenamehere -whatif

Server 2008, use remove-windowsfeature.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to reboot server simple restart of service itself will do the job, usually you need to reboot if you install some DLLs but not when you just enabled logging.